# What does "for name, val in globals(). items():" in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

the following code is representing a button, which shows imported libraries, after button clicked:

`library: ['builtins', 'builtins', 'ipywidgets', 'os', 'pathlib', 'types', 'thermo', 'ipywidgets']`

Could you please explain what is happening in line
3-6.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
import types
def imports():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            yield val.__name__
def clicked(arg):
    print("library:",list(imports()) )
    
button_download = widgets.Button(description = 'Library', button_style = 'danger') 
button_download.on_click(clicked)
display(button_download)
```

Comment: It indicates that the person who wrote this code wasn't aware of `sys.modules`. (Though that's not entirely fair; `sys.modules` contains all known  modules, whether or not they are bound to names in the global scope.)

Comment: What does your `print` statement show?

Comment: from the namings we can imply it is getting the imported modules.

Comment: It's looping over all the items in globals and if the item is of type `ModuleType` it's yielding it's name. I mean, what answer do you expect?

Comment: That code is [a lot more fragile than it looks](https://ideone.com/XT8R13), and also picks up things that aren't imported modules.

Comment: it shows ```library: ['builtins', 'builtins', 'ipywidgets', 'os', 'pathlib', 'types', 'thermo', 'ipywidgets']```

Comment: i wanted to know which libraries are used in the jupyter notebook i created

Answer (score 1):

`globals()` is a mapping/dictionary of all of the globally scoped variables that are available...globally.  Since it is a mapping/dictionary, it can be iterated over, which is what is happening.  Then the author checks whether the value is a module and returns it's name, giving you a generator that returns the name of any module in the global scope.

As mentioned in the comments, this may not be the best way to do it and may not produce the correct results, but that's what it's doing/attempting.